# chemnum: label-format not affecting \cmpd definition globally?

Tags: chemnum

When compiling the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\begin{document}

\cmpd*[label-format=\bfseries\textsuperscript,pre-label-code=\textbf{Me\textsubscript{2}L}]{Me2bdc}
\resetcmpd[1]
\cmpd*[label-format=\bfseries\textsuperscript,pre-label-code=\textbf{H\textsubscript{2}L}]{H2bdc}

\cmpd{Me2bdc} and \cmpd{H2bdc}

\cmpd[format=\bfseries\textsuperscript]{Me2bdc} and \cmpd[format=\bfseries\textsuperscript]{H2bdc}

\end{document}
```

using pdflatex, the following will be rendered:

[image: global definition vs. local definition of '1' formatting]

where the second line represents what was intended here.

According to the chemnum manual, `label-format` should be used to alter a label's property, while `format` is used where the display of individual instances of `\cmpd` is to be altered locally. However, the definition of `label-format=\bfseries\textsuperscript` seems to have no effect on the diplay of 1 (see first line). Only when `format=\bfseries\textsuperscript` is used during calling the respective compound, the formatting will take place (second line). What am I getting wrong here? Using chemnum 1.2c from an up-to-date TeX Live 2019.

Comment: I would say it is a bug, there is no key definition for label-format in the code. Report it as the github site: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misinterpretation or misunderstanding of the manual.

**label-format** is a *property* of a compound but *not an option* which can be set. Compound properties cannot be set directly by a user.

The option is called `format` and acts globally when used with `\setchemnum` and locally when used as option to `\cmpd`.

So the answer is: use `\setchemnum{format=\bfseries\textsuperscript}`.

If you  want to restrict this to only a few compounds you either need to set the format again after declaring the compounds or use a group: this works because option setting is local to grouping but compounds are always defined globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setchemnum{format=\bfseries\textsuperscript}
\cmpd*[pre-label-code=\textbf{Me\textsubscript{2}L}]{Me2bdc}
\resetcmpd
\cmpd*[pre-label-code=\textbf{H\textsubscript{2}L}]{H2bdc}
\endgroup

\cmpd{Me2bdc} and \cmpd{H2bdc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It might be reasonable to be able to set the property `label-format` compoundwise when the the label is declared. For this an option would probably be useful (and it could be called `label-format`). If this sounds like a useful feature to you please feel free to open a feature request on [github](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've added a feature request [here](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues/13). While the rendering of labels within text works as intended now using the grouping approach suggested by you, I'm still having trouble to realize differently styled labels generated by replacing tags in eps files.